# What is wrong with the following with this tuple

Tags: python

I have the following list of tuples in Python.

```
 CHECKS = [
        ('Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization', ('EMBED_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_inlining'),
        ('HTML5 Advanced Cache', ('JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE', 'CSS_HTML5_CACHE'), 'check_html5_advanced_cache'),
        ('Cookieless Resource Domain', ('RENAME_JAVASCRIPT', 'RENAME_CSS'), 'check_cookieless_resource_domain'),
        ('Minificatiopn of JS', ('MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_minifaction'),
        ('File Versioning', ('RENAME_JAVASCRIPT', 'RENAME_IMAGE', 'RENAME_CSS'), 'check_file_versioning'),
        ('Small Image Embedding', ('EMBED_IMAGE',), 'check_small_image_embedding'),
        ('Responsive Image Loading', ('RESPONSIVE_IMAGES',), 'check_responsive_image_loading')
        ('Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading', ('ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_async_js_and_css_loading'),
        ('JS Pre-Execution', ('PRE_EXECUTE_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_pre_execution'),
    ]
```

Upon execution it throws the error

`File "FEO_processor.py", line 14, in FEOProcessor
    ('Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading', ('ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_async_js_and_css_loading'),
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

What am I missing here.

Comment: Missing comma in ...'check_responsive_image_loading')

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma:

```
('...', ('RESPONSIVE_IMAGES',), 'check_responsive_image_loading')
                                                                 ↑ HERE
```

Comment: This arrow changed my life: ↑

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Thanks. Nice Christmas present. :)

Comment: Next Christmas I'll introduce ↓ :)